# JSON iterating an array

Tags: python

I seem to be hitting a strange blocker trying to access some data items in a JSON data structure.

I need to iterate over the items within the data array in within the JSON but can't work out how to get to them.

I've tried this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

file = 'data.json'

with open(file) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for host in data:
    print host["host"]

    for proto in host["protocols"]:
        print proto
```

This gets me my protocol versions, but I can't work out how to get to the items in the data array.

```
[
  {
    "host": "192.168.0.1",
    "port": 443,
    "protocols": {
      "v1": {
        "data": ["12345","54354334534253245342"],
        "tag": "abc"
      },
      "v2": {
        "data": ["45678"],
        "tag": "xyz"
      }
    },
    "processed": false
  },
  {
    "host": "192.168.0.3",
    "port": 443,
    "protocols": {
      "v1": {
        "data": ["12345","43434","543543543"],
        "tag": "abc"
      },
      "v2": {
        "data": ["45678"],
        "tag": "xyz"
      },
      "v3": {
        "data": ["910111"],
        "tag": "ttt"
      }
    },
    "processed": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protocols is a dictionary, so you would need to iterate it a bit differently:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

file = 'data.json'

with open(file) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for host in data:
    print host["host"]

    for version, proto in host["protocols"].iteritems():
        print version
        print proto
        print proto["data"]
```